# How to View Who has Been Editing Specific Information on Leads

Tags: user-admin

I'm in charge of maintaining data integrity for my company's SF database. I'm finding information for certain fields is being entered incorrectly on what seems to be a pattern basis.

I'm trying to figure out which users are responsible for this problem so we can work together to fix it in the future. However, I can only see the Last Modified By field which doesn't show me what fields they edited, or what fields were edited by whom in the past.

Is there a way to view specific changes to a lead from the past?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Audit Trails as specified [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_audit_trail.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=0)

> Field Audit Trail lets you define a policy to retain archived field
>   history data up to ten years, independent of field history tracking.
>   This feature helps you comply with industry regulations related to
>   audit capability and data retention.

However, some fields can't be tracked:

1. Formula, roll-up summary, or auto-number fields
2. Created By and Last
       Modified By
3. Expected Revenue field on opportunities
4. Master Solution
5. Title or the Master Solution Details fields on solutions
6. Long text
       fields
7. Multi-select fields